# Updating a Material-UI TextField onBlur with Formik (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

I'm currently rendering an editable table that lets the user bulk edit several user's information at once (See Image). I'm using Material-UI's `<TextField/>` and Formik to handle the form's submission and state.

[image: Bulk Edit]

I'm trying to:

1. Keep the `<TextField />`'s value and Formik's state in sync
2. Whenever I remove one row (when x is clicked), to reflect the changes in the whole table.

This table comprises generally of approximately 266 input fields. Using `onChange` event brings serious performance concerns. Therefore I've had to apply several component wrapping, and memoization to prevent all the input fields from re-rendering every time a single input had changed.

I've been successfully made this work (almost in a good performant way), **except** whenever I delete a row. The old value seems to remain, while Formik's value does change.

The problem appears to be in how the `defaultValue` and `value` properties of the `<TextField />` work.

The `value` property seems to create a controlled component and will reflect 1-on-1 whatever value you pass in there. I've tried setting Formik's `field.value` directly into the field. Unfortunately, the value wouldn't update the field as I'm currently using the onBlur event to do it (and will never show the changes). If I were to use the onChange, everything would work, except performance would be garbage as it would update all the fields.

On the other hand, the `defaultValue` makes the component uncontrolled. Nonetheless, I'm able to edit the value, and even update Formik's state `onBlur`!. There is **one problem**, though... whenever I delete a row, the value inside the `<TextField/>` **does not update** (But Formik **does** reflect the change).

It seems that there is some caching going on inside the `<TextField />` component, as I've tried logging the field's value, which is the one that I'm currently passing to `defaultValue`, and it **is showing** the changes.

I've also tried:

- Tinkering with `defaultValue` and `value`
- Setting a `useState` hook to work as a middleman between Formik's value and the component's
- Removing the memoization.
- Manually implemented the memoization comparison.

And none of them seems to work... What should I do in this case?

For reference, here's the code I'm using:

---

Here's the textfield I'm currently using:

**FormText**

```js
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { useField } from 'formik';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { TextProps } from '../../../Fields/TextField/textfield-definitions';

type ComponentProps = TextProps & {
  useBlur?: boolean;
  errorMessage: string | undefined;
};

export const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = memo(props => {
  const {
    className,
    name,
    label,
    placeholder,
    required,
    useBlur,
    error,
    errorMessage,
    onChange,
    onBlur,
    value,
  } = props;

  // We wrap it so we don't block the heap stack!
  // Improves performance considerably
  // https://medium.com/trabe/react-syntheticevent-reuse-889cd52981b6
  const fireBlur = (e: any) => {
    // React removes
    e.persist();
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      if (onBlur) {
        onBlur(e);
      }
    }, 0);
  };

  const setInnerState = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {};

  const fireChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.persist();
    setInnerState(e);
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      if (onChange) {
        onChange(e);
      }
    }, 0);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      className={className}
      name={name}
      label={label}
      type={props.type}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      defaultValue={value}
      variant="outlined"
      required={required}
      error={error}
      helperText={<span>{error ? errorMessage : ''}</span>}
      onChange={useBlur ? undefined : fireChange}
      onBlur={useBlur ? fireBlur : undefined}
    />
  );
});

export const SchonText: React.FC<TextProps> = props => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props.name);
  const hasError = !!meta.error && !!meta.touched;
  return (
    <Component
      value={field.value}
      {...props}
      error={hasError}
      errorMessage={meta.error}
      onChange={field.onChange}
      onBlur={field.onChange}
    />
  );
};

export default SchonText;
```

Here are the components that are consuming it: 
**TableRow**

```js
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { TableRow, TableCell, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Close } from '@material-ui/icons';
import {
  FormText,
  FormSelect,
  FormTextArea,
  Button,
} from '../../../../../../components';
import { Student, Gender } from '../../../../../../graphql/types';
import { SelectOption } from '../../../../../../components/Fields/Select/select-definitions';

type BulkAddTableRowProps = {
  student: Student;
  index: number;
  deleteStudent: (index: number) => void;
};
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: `0px`,
  },
}));

const selectOptions: SelectOption[] = [
  {
    label: 'M',
    value: Gender.Male,
  },
  {
    label: 'F',
    value: Gender.Female,
  },
];

const Component: React.FC<BulkAddTableRowProps> = props => {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const { student, index } = props;
  const deleteStudent = () => props.deleteStudent(index);
  return (
    <TableRow className={styles.root} hover={true}>
      <TableCell>{index + 1}</TableCell>
      <TableCell className={styles.root}>
        <FormText
          name={`students[${index}].name.firstName`}
          value={student.name.firstName}
          useBlur={true}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FormText
          name={`students[${index}].name.lastName`}
          value={student.name.lastName}
          useBlur={true}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FormSelect
          name={`students[${index}].gender`}
          value={student.gender}
          options={selectOptions}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FormText
          type="email"
          name={`students[${index}].email`}
          value={student.email}
          useBlur={true}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FormText
          type="date"
          name={`students[${index}].birthDate`}
          value={student.birthDate}
          useBlur={true}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FormTextArea
          name={`students[${index}].allergies`}
          value={student.allergies}
          useBlur={true}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FormTextArea
          name={`students[${index}].diseases`}
          value={student.diseases}
          useBlur={true}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <Button onClick={deleteStudent}>
          <Close />
        </Button>
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
};

function shouldRemainTheSame(
  prevProps: BulkAddTableRowProps,
  newProps: BulkAddTableRowProps,
): boolean {
  const prevStudent = prevProps.student;
  const newStudent = newProps.student;
  const isNameTheSame = Object.keys(prevStudent.name).every(key => {
    return prevStudent.name[key] === newStudent.name[key];
  });
  const isStudentTheSame = Object.keys(prevStudent)
    .filter(x => x !== 'name')
    .every(key => prevStudent[key] === newStudent[key]);
  return (
    isNameTheSame && isStudentTheSame && prevProps.index === newProps.index
  );
}

export const BulkAddTableRow = memo(Component, shouldRemainTheSame);
export default BulkAddTableRow;
```

**StudentBulkTableView**

```js
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import {
  FieldArray,
  FieldArrayRenderProps,
  getIn,
  useFormikContext,
} from 'formik';
import { Student, Gender } from '../../../../graphql/types/index';
import {
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  TableBody,
  makeStyles,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Button, Select } from '../../../../components';
import { SelectOption } from '../../../../components/Fields/Select/select-definitions';
import { emptyStudent, BulkAddStudentValues } from '../shared';
import BulkAddTableRow from './components/TableRow/index';

type ComponentProps = {
  push: (obj: any) => void;
  remove: (index: number) => undefined;
  students: Student[];
  setFieldValue: (
    field: 'students',
    value: any,
    shouldValidate?: boolean | undefined,
  ) => void;
};

const selectOptions: SelectOption[] = [
  {
    label: 'M',
    value: Gender.Male,
  },
  {
    label: 'F',
    value: Gender.Female,
  },
];

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: `0px`,
  },
}));

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = memo(props => {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const { students, push, remove, setFieldValue } = props;
  function deleteStudent(index: number) {
    if (!window.confirm('¿Desea borrar este estudiante?')) {
      return;
    }
    remove(index);
  }

  const addStudent = () => push(emptyStudent());

  const selectAllOptions = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    students.forEach(student => (student.gender = evt.target.value as Gender));
    console.log(students);
    setFieldValue('students', students);
  };

  return (
    <>
      Cambiar el género a todos los estudiantes:{' '}
      <Select
        name="select_all"
        options={selectOptions}
        onChange={selectAllOptions}
      />{' '}
      <br />
      <Paper style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Table style={{ width: '100%', padding: 'root' }}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>#</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Nombre</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Apellido</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Género</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Email</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Cumpleaños</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Alergias</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Enfermedades</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Acción</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {students.map((student, index) => (
              <BulkAddTableRow
                key={`${student.name}-${index}`}
                student={student}
                deleteStudent={deleteStudent}
                index={index}
              />
            ))}
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell colSpan={8}></TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Button onClick={addStudent}>+</Button>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    </>
  );
});

export const StudentBulkTableView: React.FC = props => {
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext<BulkAddStudentValues>();

  return (
    <FieldArray name="students">
      {({ remove, push, form }: FieldArrayRenderProps) => {
        const students = getIn(form.values, 'students') as Student[];

        return (
          <Component
            setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
            remove={remove}
            push={push}
            students={students}
          />
        );
      }}
    </FieldArray>
  );
};
export default StudentBulkTableView;
```

P.S: I've excluded the `<FormTextArea />` component as it's exactly the same as the `<FormText />` component.

Comment: Can you share all of this code I need same thing .

Comment: @PrateekPareek Sure, I'm going to add an updated version.

Comment: ok please all the include how you are adding and removing row and getting data on submit

Comment: @PrateekPareek I've posted an answer. See below

Comment: Thank you so much you save my job man

Comment: @PrateekPareek Glad it helped 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the behavior you describe, it sounds like there might be a problem with the `key` you're using for each of the rows.

```
<BulkAddTableRow
  key={`${student.name}-${index}`}
```

It looks like `student.name` is an object, which means your `key`s would be `"[object Object]-0"`, `"[object Object]-1"`, etc. Index-based keys will cause problems when deleting rows, because React won't know that the value for that index has changed.

Here's an article describing the problem: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

You can console.log the `key` for each of the rows, and if they are `[object-Object]` plus the index, you can do something like this:

```
<BulkAddTableRow
  key={`${student.name.firstName}-${student.name.lastName}`}
```

Comment: That was it that was it that was it!!! Problem solved! I see. It seems I got bitten by that problem, even though I thought I could just get over that problem if I added a piece of text before the index... Seems I'll definitely be more careful from now on!!!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

This answer goes for @PrateekPareek which I'll be sharing how to implement a performant onBlur using Formik 2.

This will be using Hooks and this greatly differs from what I have posted above.

I'm also using Material UI.

The trick here is to use an internal state to handle the Material UI TextField and propagate the change to Formik using onBlur. Unfortunately, this has a drawback in which pre-filled fields such as passwords aren't detected.

To mitigate this, there is an alternate method that uses a debounce function and a useEffect to propagate the onChange event when the user types vs using onBlur (Which I'm not sharing here as I haven't created it yet).

I generally tend to wrap my Form Textfields in their own component, so it's just a matter of dropping them in the component in use.

There's a "disablePerformance" prop that basically lets Formik handle the entire component.

```
import React, { memo, useState } from 'react';
import {
  TextField,
  TextFieldProps,
} from '../../../../../stories/Fields/TextField';
import { useField } from 'formik';

export type FormTextProps = Omit<TextFieldProps, 'name'> & {
  name: string;
  disablePerformance?: boolean;
};

export const FormText: React.FC<FormTextProps> = memo((props) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props.name);
  const error = !!meta.error && meta.touched;

  /**
   * For performance reasons (possible due to CSS in JS issues), heavy views
   * affect re-renders (Formik changes state in every re-render), bringing keyboard
   * input to its knees. To control this, we create a setState that handles the field's inner
   * (otherwise you wouldn't be able to type) and then propagate the change to Formik onBlur and
   * onFocus.
   */
  const [fieldValue, setFieldValue] = useState<string | number>(field.value);
  const { disablePerformance, ...otherProps } = props;
  const onChange = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFieldValue(evt.target.value);
  };
  const onBlur = (evt: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    field.onChange({
      target: {
        name: props.name,
        value: evt.target.value || '',
      },
    });
  };

  // Will set depending on the performance props
  const performanceProps = disablePerformance
    ? field
    : {
        ...field,
        value: fieldValue,
        onChange,
        onBlur,
        onFocus: onBlur,
      };

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        {...otherProps}
        error={error}
        helperText={meta.touched && meta.error}
        {...performanceProps}
      />
    </>
  );
});

export default FormText;
```

Just for reference, here's the TextField, which is a wrapper for Material-UI so I can set some defaults.

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import {
  TextField as MuiTextField,
  TextFieldProps as MuiTextFieldProps,
} from '@material-ui/core';

export type TextFieldProps = MuiTextFieldProps & {};

export const TextField: React.FC<TextFieldProps> = memo((props) => {
  // muiProps => The props for MaterialUI
  const { ...muiProps } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <MuiTextField
        fullWidth={true}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
          style: { textTransform: 'uppercase' },
        }}
        {...muiProps}
      >
        {props.children}
      </MuiTextField>
    </>
  );
});

export default TextField;
```